# Get <li> value attribute on click?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to do something which I thought should be fairly simple. I'm using Bootstrap for the Navbar, and jQuery to find (dropdown menu)list items on click. Events are firing correctly, but 'value' is always returned as undefined.

Navbar code:

```
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Order By<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu sort-options" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#" >Default</a></li>
                    <li><a value="title">Title</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#" value="date-created-oldest">Oldest Parts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" value="date-created-newest">Newest Parts</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#" value="stock-volume-largest">Smallest Volume</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" value="stock-volume-smallest">Largest Volume</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

jQuery snippet:

```
$('.sort-options li').click(function () {
    var sort = $(this).attr('value');
        opts = {};
        alert('Value: ' + $(this).attr('value'));
```

The click event fires properly on list items, but I the value is always undefined or 0. I tried using data- annotations as well but had the same results. Anyone know what the deal is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
var sort = $(this).find('a').attr('value');
```

Because `$(this)` refers to `li`, but `li` does not have attribute `value`. In our case you need search in `li` tag `a` and get attribute `value`

Comment: 1+.. or `$('a', this).attr('value')`.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>show the value of li</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="pathnameofcss">
</head>
<body>

    <div id="user"></div>


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <ul id="pageno">
    <li value="1">1</li>
    <li value="2">2</li>
    <li value="3">3</li>
    <li value="4">4</li>
    <li value="5">5</li>
    <li value="6">6</li>
    <li value="7">7</li>
    <li value="8">8</li>
    <li value="9">9</li>
    <li value="10">10</li>

    </ul>

    <script src="pathnameofjs" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:-

```
$("li").click(function ()
{       
var a = $(this).attr("value");

$("#user").html(a);//here the clicked value is showing in the div name user
console.log(a);//here the clicked value is showing in the console
});
```

CSS:-

```
ul{
display: flex;
list-style-type:none;
padding: 20px;
}

li{
padding: 20px;
}
```